# renaming a range of columns in pandas dataframe (really new to coding and a kindhearted idiot)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm really sorry, I'm sure this is a stupid question and I have spent days combing for answers here and on other resources but I'm just too new to this and need to learn this (PhD pressure)

I'm trying to edit a pandas dataframe that contains a number of discrete psychological measurements. at the moment it looks like this.

```
age   country    v_1    v_2    v_3   v_4    v_5     v_6   v_7
26    Ireland     2      3      1     5      3       2     1
30    Germany     3      5      5     1      3       4     1
44    Ireland     1      4      5     2      2       1     2
```

I want to be able to select columns (i.e. v_1 to v_5) and be able to rename them using an abbreviation followed by a number (which increases by 1 each time it runs).

so, for example, I have a short emotional scale (SES) which has 5 items (v_1 to v_5 in my dataframe) and I want to run a piece of code which returns

```
age   country    SES1   SES2   SES3  SES4   SES5     v_6   v_7
26    Ireland     2      3      1     5      3       2     1
30    Germany     3      5      5     1      3       4     1
44    Ireland     1      4      5     2      2       1     2
```

and ideally, I'd like to be able to run it again for v_6 etc, with a new abbreviation.

I have tried using something like:

```
for col in df[v_1:v_5]:
    abr = ' SES'
    1 = 0
    df.rename(columns = {col: + str(i)}, inplace = True)
```

Again, I'm sorry if this is obvious, or just stupid but any help that does'nt point me to another answer on the site (unless I just missed one) would really help a guy out.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm using the code posted below now and not getting any error it's just not making changes to the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close!

```py
df.rename(columns={"v_%d"%i: "SES%d"%i for i in range(1,6)}, inplace=True)
```

Here we're using a dictionary comprehension to build up the mapping from the old column names to the new. You could also use a `for` loop for clarity since there's unlikely to be much in it performance-wise.

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I try this it throws a syntax error with i as the point where the error occurs.

    nd.rename(columns={"v_564"%i: "SSRQ%d"i for i in range(1,29)}, inplace=True) 
      File "<ipython-input-40-0b06bc4a3da3>", line 1
        nd.rename(columns={"v_564"%i: "SSRQ%d"i for i in range(1,29)}, inplace=True)
                                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: So now the code doesn't throw an error but nothing happens to the data frame.

Comment: What's the output of `list(df)`?